# HTML - Split into 70% and 30%

Tags: html, css

So In my website I am using the current code to split the page in 50% and 50%. But I want to chang it to 70% and 30%. The code below is my current code.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
}

.split {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="split left">
  <div class="centered">
    <h2>70%</h2>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="split right">
  <div class="centered">
    <h2>30%</h2>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
     
</body>
</html>
```

I tried changing the `left: 50%;` to 70%, but that just moves the text a bit to the right.

Comment: get rid of position:fixed

Comment: @TemaniAfif Why is that? Ahmad Habib's answer works while using `position: fixed;`.

Comment: because it's a *poor* way to build layout. There is more convenient techniques: https://jsfiddle.net/ev163c0u/

Comment: @TemaniAfif Hm, I see. But I guess I need it, since I also have a top nav bar, exactly like this one: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_topnav . Or what do you think?

Comment: another reason why you need to get rid of position:fixed.

Comment: @TemaniAfif But what I am doing wrong here then: https://jsfiddle.net/5zq47jcn/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `50%` from the `.split` class and add `width: 70%` in `.left`, `width: 30%` in `.right`.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
}

.split {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 70%;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 30%;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="split left">
  <div class="centered">
    <h2>70%</h2>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="split right">
  <div class="centered">
    <h2>30%</h2>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle code**](https://jsfiddle.net/a71kr65w/)